# Intro to node.js - Print data from 3 urls (http.get)

Tags: node.js, server, server-side

I'm doing an introduction to node.js using **learnyounode**. I wonder if you could help realize this thing: asynchronism.

So, here is the problem:

> This problem is the same as the previous problem (HTTP COLLECT) in
>   that     you need to use http.get(). However, this time you will be
>   provided with     three URLs as the first three command-line
>   arguments.
>         You must collect the complete content provided to you by each of the URLs     and print it to the console (stdout). You don't need to
>   print out the     length, just the data as a String; one line per URL.
>   The catch is that you     must print them out in the same order as the
>   URLs are provided to you as     command-line arguments.

and here is my bad solution who, in fact, don't work.

```
var http = require('http');
var message = [];

for (var i = 2; i < 5; i++)
http.get(process.argv[i], function (res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');

  res.on('data', function(line) {
    message[i] += line.toString();
  });
  res.on('end', function(line) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      console.log(message[i]);
  });
});
```

**UPDATE**
So I tried a similar approach to your solution.

Here goes:

```
var http = require('http');
var count = 0;
var message = ["","",""];

for (var i = 2; i < 5; i++)
{
  http.get(process.argv[i], function (res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function( line ) {
      message[count] += line.toString();
    });

    res.on('end', function(line) {
      count++;
      if(count !== 3)
        return;
      else
        printOutput();
    });
  });
}

function printOutput(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      console.log(message[i]);
}
```

But the output is lagged: / (not in the right order)

> 1. CURRENT: "He has not got the skite and watch out for the bogged Trent from punchy blue with the dry to the Vinnie's It'll be flanno
>      where flat out like the slabs..."
> 2. EXPECTED: "He's got a massive coldie my watch out for the smoko We're jackaroo going on she'll be right servo dramas.."
> 3. CURRENT ". He has not got a banana bender piece of piss the dry as a budgie smugglers Come a flamin clacker you little bog standard
>      ripper The cross them to his blood's worth bottling flamin the cunning
>      of a rip snorter.."
> 4. EXPECTED: "He has not got the skite and watch out for the bogged Trent from punchy blue with the dry to the Vinnie's It'll be flanno
>      where flat out like the slabs..."
> 5. CURRENT: "He's got a massive coldie my watch out for the smoko We're jackaroo going on she'll be right servo dramas.."
> 6. EXPECTED: "He has not got a banana bender piece of piss the dry as a budgie smugglers Come a flamin clacker you little bog standard
>      ripper The cross them to his blood's worth bottling flamin the cunning
>      of a rip snorter..."
> 7. CURRENT: ""
> 8. EXPECTED ""

Comment: That's because you're using count to index the messages instead of the correct index. See my updated response. You need to capture the current value of I and use that for data receiving. `var currentIndex = i;` and `message[currentIndex] += line.toString();`

Answer (score 2):

a more cleaner way to do it asynchronously is by having all Promises in an array and calling **Promise.all()** on that array

```
var http = require('http');

promises = [
    promiseLoad(process.argv[2]),
    promiseLoad(process.argv[3]),
    promiseLoad(process.argv[4])
];
Promise.all(promises).then(function(res){
    console.log(res);
});

function promiseLoad(url) {
  var body = '';
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    http.get(url, function(res) {
      res.on('data', function(d) {
        body += d;
      });
      res.on('end', function() {
        resolve(body);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: This is the fanciest way to do it and the way that I would suggest unless.  The only thing that I can see is if the problem wants messages printed **in order** and **ASAP**.  With `Promise.all()` I don't think you'll get any output until the request finishes.  So if 1 finishes then 2, you won't get immediate output even though it is available.  The question is unclear about this case though, so I would definitely use a `Promise.all()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the prior request to reach the 'end' event before processing the next request, hence the asynchronous challenge. This can be accomplished via callbacks, or promises.

Promise implementation:

```
var http = require('http');

promiseLoad(process.argv[2])
  .then(promiseLoad(process.argv[3])
  .then(promiseLoad(process.argv[4]);

function promiseLoad(url) {
  var body = '';

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    http.get(url, function(res) {
      res.on('data', function(d) {
        body += d;
      });

      res.on('end', function() {
        console.log(body);
        resolve();
      });
    });
  });


}
```

I will leave the callback implementation to you as an exercise. As a starting point, the next request will have to be fired only once the end event if fired.

**UPDATE:**

To load these truly asynchronously and at the same time, your code will work with minor modifications. You need to simply wait for end to be called 3 times and only log at that point indicating that all loading is complete:

```
var http = require('http');
var count = 0;
var message = [];

for (var i = 2; i < 5; i++)
http.get(process.argv[i], function (res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  var correctIndex = i;
  res.on('data', function(line) {
    message[correctIndex] += line.toString();
  });
  res.on('end', function(line) {
    count++;
    if(count !== 3) return;

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      console.log(message[i]);
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't think the second piece of code will work as you hope - by the time `res.on('data'` for the first iteration is called, `i` will already be 4. For loops over asynchronous code are tricky.

Comment: I think your first code block is actually wrong.  There is no logic in `promiseLoad` to maintain the order of output and the requests are all started at the same time.

Comment: @JoostVunderink - Updated to capture the correct value of `i` for message indexing.

Comment: @zero298 - That's incorrect. These requests are executed sequentially, and in order. The first request will finish and print the body contents and only __then__ will the next request begin.

Comment: @BrandonSmith It should work fine this way now. One small bug that's left is `message[correctIndex] += line.toString()`. `message[0]` is undefined instead of an empty string, so it will end up as a string starting with `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to say that the answer [already here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34549082/691711) that says to use `Promise.all()` is the way that I would suggest.  However, I want to point out a particular scenario where it might not cover your needs.

Consider that you have 3 requests:

```
"Service" | "Time to complete"
----------------------------
  A       |       3 
  B       |       1
  C       |       5
  D       |       4
```

And you're going to use a load handler similar to what has already been mentioned:

```
// Url loader
function load(url) {
    var message = "";
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        http.get(url, function (res) {
            // Add message piece
            res.on("data", function (data) {
                message += data;
            });
            // Resolve whole message
            res.on("end", function (data) {
                resolve(message);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

### Printing After Everything Finishes

If you use the `Promise.all()`, you are going to have to wait for all of the requests to finish before you see any output.  So if we output a timestamp with our data, we will get the following:

**Code**

```
/*
Wait for all promises to complete and then 
print out all of their collected data
*/
Promise.all(promises).then(function (res) {
    res.forEach(function (data) {
        timestamp(data);
    });
});
```

**Output**

```
[14:9:4.106] Start
[14:9:10.335] aaaa
[14:9:10.336] bbbb
[14:9:10.336] cccc
[14:9:10.336] dddd
```

Where it takes **6** seconds after we start to see any output from the result of our services.

### Printing As Soon As Possible

Comparatively, if we wanted to print output while we are getting results from our service calls, we need to print the result as the service finishes, but not until all "prior" services are done.  With that in mind, we could do could do something like this:

**Code**

```
promises[0].then(function (dataA) {
    timestamp(dataA);
    promises[1].then(function (dataB) {
        timestamp(dataB);
        promises[2].then(function (dataC) {
            timestamp(dataC);
            promises[3].then(function (dataD) {
                timestamp(dataD);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**Output**

```
[14:16:19.245] Start
[14:16:22.974] aaaa
[14:16:22.975] bbbb
[14:16:25.474] cccc
[14:16:25.474] dddd
```

Here, we see the start, then only **3** seconds later we print out both **Service A** and **Service B**.  We see **A** because its service just resolved and **B** because its service was already done, but we didn't want to print until **A** was finished.  Similarly, **C** and **D** show up about **2** seconds after **B**.

Now, that code is somewhat verbose, so we could write a recursive function to handle all that nesting for us.

```
// Function to print an array of promises in order
function cascadeInOrder(promiseArr) {
    var curr = 0;

    // This closure is going to recursively print out our promises
    function nexter(data) {
        if (data) {
            timestamp(data);
        }
        // Have the next promise print its data whenever it is done
        promiseArr[curr += 1].then(nexter);
    }

    // Wait for our first promise to finish and have it kick off the next
    promiseArr[curr].then(nexter);
}
```

I haven't really run into many uses cases where we need to make "synchronous" usage of asynchronous data, but I'm sure that there is a potential need for it somewhere.

**Test Code Used**:

Change the `method` variable if you want to use the other methods.

```js
/*global Promise*/

"use strict";

// Provide response times for fake services
function getUrlTiming(url) {
    var timing = 0;
    switch (url) {
    case "a":
        timing = 3000;
        break;
    case "b":
        timing = 1000;
        break;
    case "c":
        timing = 5000;
        break;
    case "d":
        timing = 4000;
        break;
    default:
        timing = 0;
        break;
    }
    return timing;
}

// Service to wrap events
function Service() {
    this.listeners = [];
}
Service.prototype = {
    on: function (event, cb) {
        if (!this.listeners[event]) {
            this.listeners[event] = [];
        }
        this.listeners[event].push(cb);
    },
    emit: function (event, details) {
        if (this.listeners[event]) {
            this.listeners[event].forEach(function (cb) {
                cb(details);
            });
        }
    }
};

// Make a fake http module
var http = {
    get: function (url, cb) {
        // Make an event emiiter
        var req = new Service();

        // If we got a callback
        if (cb && (typeof cb === "function")) {
            // Call it to set up listeners
            cb(req);
        }

        // Make a promise to resolve after the service finishes
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var network,
                message = "",
                part = 0,
                maxParts = 4;

            /*
            Create a network simulation to send a massage in parts
            until the request finishes
            */
            network = setInterval(function () {
                // If the message isn't complete
                if (part < 4) {
                    // Add to the whole message tracker
                    message += url;
                    // Emit that we got data
                    req.emit("data", url);
                    // Increment how far in the message we are
                    part += 1;
                } else {
                    // Stop transmitting
                    clearInterval(network);
                    // Emit the end of the request
                    req.emit("end", message);
                    // Resolve the request
                    resolve(url);
                }
            }, (getUrlTiming(url) / maxParts));
        });
    }
};

// Url loader
function load(url) {
    var message = "";
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        http.get(url, function (res) {
            // Add message piece
            res.on("data", function (data) {
                message += data;
            });
            // Resolve whole message
            res.on("end", function (data) {
                resolve(message);
            });
        });
    });
}

// Get a readable time
function getTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    return (now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds() + "." + now.getMilliseconds());
}

// Print a timestamped message
function timestamp(message) {
    console.log("[%s] %s", getTime(), message);
}

// Function to print an array of promises in order
function cascadeInOrder(promiseArr) {
    var curr = 0;

    // This closure is going to recursively print out our promises
    function nexter(data) {
        if (data) {
            timestamp(data);
        }
        // Have the next promise print its data whenever it is done
        promiseArr[curr += 1].then(nexter);
    }

    // Wait for our first promise to finish and have it kick off the next
    promiseArr[curr].then(nexter);
}

/*
No matter what, we want all of our requests to 
start right now, and effectively at the same time.
We don't want to start one after another finishes
*/
var promises = [
    load("a"),
    load("b"),
    load("c"),
    load("d")
];

/*
Which method we want to use to test our stuff
Change between [1, 2, 3] for each method listed
below.  1 for Promise.all(), 2 for ASAP printing,
and 3 for the verbose version of 2.
*/
var method = 3;

// Note when we started
timestamp("Start");

if (method === 1) {
    /*
    Wait for all promises to complete and then 
    print out all of their collected data
    */
    Promise.all(promises).then(function (res) {
        res.forEach(function (data) {
            timestamp(data);
        });
    });
} else if (method === 2) {
    /*
    Print each ones data as soon as it is 
    available; but make sure to do it in order
    */
    cascadeInOrder(promises);
} else if (method === 3) {
    /*
    This is the same as the "cascadeInOrder" function,
    except written without recursion and more verbosely.
    */
    promises[0].then(function (dataA) {
        timestamp(dataA);
        promises[1].then(function (dataB) {
            timestamp(dataB);
            promises[2].then(function (dataC) {
                timestamp(dataC);
                promises[3].then(function (dataD) {
                    timestamp(dataD);
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Luís Melo

Here's my solution after going through this thread:

```
var http = require('http');
var bl   = require('bl') 

promises = [
    promiseLoad(process.argv[2]),
    promiseLoad(process.argv[3]),
    promiseLoad(process.argv[4])
];

Promise.all(promises).then(function(res) {

  for(i=0; i<promises.length; i++) {
    console.log(res[i]);
  }
});

function promiseLoad(url) {
  var body = '';
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    http.get(url, function (response) { 
    response.setEncoding('utf8'); 
       response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {  
         resolve(data.toString())
       }))  
     })
  });
}
```

Here's the official solution in case you want to compare notes:

```
 var http = require('http')  
 var bl = require('bl')  
 var results = []  
 var count = 0  

 function printResults () {  
   for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {  
     console.log(results[i])  
   }  
 }  

 function httpGet (index) {  
   http.get(process.argv[2 + index], function (response) {  
     response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {  
       if (err) {  
         return console.error(err)  
       }  

       results[index] = data.toString()  
       count++  

       if (count === 3) {  
         printResults()  
       }  
     }))  
   })  
 }  

 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {  
   httpGet(i)  
 }
```